# GhostDoc how to get attributes of a property?

Tags: c#, xml-documentation, code-documentation, ghostdoc

I use the aforesaid documentation tool on Visual Studio 2017.

I can reach the GhostDoc Options > Rules > Property Template and customize the code. I have a property like;

```
[Display(Name="Text here")]
[Required]
public int CompanyId {get;set;}
```

I want to reach the "Required" and "DisplayName" attributes and use them in summary. Is there any way to accomplish it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://support.submain.com/community/a75/how-to-reference-an-attribute-on-a-method-or-property.aspx for information on how to use the attribute names in the template. The attribute values are not available ATM but are coming soon.